# How to exempt CSRF Protection on direct_to_template

Tags: django, csrf

I have a flow in my django application in which I redirect the user to another service (e.g. PayPal) which after some its own processing, returns the user back on my own server. The returning point on my server is a simple HTML success page which I render using direct_to_template.

For some odd reasons, the other server sends a POST request and hence the user sees a CSRF token missing error as the other server doesn't send back any CSRF token.

How do I exempt a direct_to_template view from CSRF tokens?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator to disable CSRF protection for a particular view.

Say your url pattern is:

```
('^my_page/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'my_page.html'})
```

Add the following import to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

Then change the url pattern to:

```
('^my_page/$', csrf_exempt(direct_to_template), {'template': 'my_page.html'})
```

Answer (score 74):

You can Use `@csrf_exempt` decorator to excempt csrf token for this you have to import

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

then write `@csrf_exempt` before your view

this will work properly :)

Comment: this does not answer the question at all, as he wants to use the built in direct_to_template function, not decorate his own views

Comment: You also can use  `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)` on `dispatch` method for yours class-based views.

Comment: @MarkMishyn can you elaborate a bit more? e.g. from where do we import `method_decorator`? edit: `from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator`